# Download File using CURL with SHAREPOINT 2013

Tags: curl, sharepoint-2013, download

I need to download a file using CURL from sharepoint 2013.

I am able to authenticate and the server returns a OK for NTLM authentication. However the file does not get downloaded.

The server returns a HTML file with "Something Went Wrong" error.

Is there any thing that I may be missing.

The code I used is `curl -vv -O -L --cookie-jar ./cookie --ntlm --user USER:PASS URL`

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. It is really hard to help otherwise.

Comment: curl -vv -O -L --cookie-jar ./cookie --ntlm --user USER:PASS URL.

Comment: Does the URL end in `.html` or some other webpage ext? To download using cURL, you need to specify the link to the file itself. So, if you want to download an excel, you need to specify a URL to the file, which will most likely end in `.xlsx` and not `.html`.

Comment: The URL I gave was for the .xlsx file from sharepoint. One thig I found was we need to have below URL format:-
http://spsite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://spsite/Documents/sample.docx

Comment: In that case, all you need to give cURL is the source URL `http://spsite/Documents/sample.docx`. Or put the URL in double-quotes

Comment: I captured the URL from Internet Explorer's Network monitor. Used the URL to directly get the file using Internet Explorer. However If I try the same URL using cURL It throws Authentication Error. ERROR below:-

Access denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically.

Comment: Just to be clear, there's 2 things you can do:
`curl -vv -O -L --cookie-jar ./cookie --ntlm --user USER:PASS http://spsite/Documents/sample.docx`
or
`curl -vv -O -L --cookie-jar ./cookie --ntlm --user USER:PASS "http://spsite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://spsite/Documents/sample.docx"`